# Extract image meta data and set field values on Media upload

Tags: media, 9

I'm extracting IPTC and EXIF data when the user uploads an image using the Media Library UI.

Using `hook_form_alter` I can get the URI of the uploaded file in the `media_library_add_form_upload` form, and extract the data from it. So far, so good.

However, the form does not (yet?) contain the other fields attached to the media type (e.g. title, description, copyright) so I can't set the values.

How can I set the values in the form that is shown after I've selected and upload an image?

Answer (score 0):

The form fields are nested under `$form['media'][0]`. Having extracted data from the uploaded file, we can set the data as default values on the fields.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_media_form_alter().
 */
function ds_media_exif_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id !== 'media_library_add_form_upload') {
    return;
  }

  if (!array_key_exists('upload', $values)) {
    return;
  }

  $upload_id = $values['upload'][0];
  $file = File::load($upload_id);
  $uri = $file->getFileUri();

  // Extract exif, iptc data here.
  $data = extractFileData($uri);

  // Title defaults to the file name.
  if (isset($data['title'])) {
    $form['media'][0]['fields']['name']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $data['title'];
    // Set alt field to title.
    $form['media'][0]['fields']['field_media_image']['widget'][0]['#default_value']['alt'] = $data['title'];
  }

  // Some more fields: field_description and field_copyright.
  $form['media'][0]['fields']['field_description']['widget'][0]['#default_value'] = $data['description'] ?: '';
  $form['media'][0]['fields']['field_copyright']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $data['copyright'] ?: '';
}
```